# comparing the index of element in scala list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have 2 list

```
val listA = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Marry")
val listB = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Marry")
```

Now I want to know whether the index of all occurrences of `Harry` in both the list are same or not. What is the best way to do it in scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use iterators to compare only as much as needed, like so:

```
def indexesOf(ls: List[String], word: String) =
  ls.iterator.zipWithIndex.collect { case (`word`, i) => i }

indexesOf(listA, "Harry") sameElements indexesOf(listB, "Harry")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @megri I read about it and understood it too.

Answer (score 2):

You could `.zip` the lists together and then use `.exists` to check whether there is a tuple where one equals `"Harry"` and the other does not:

```
scala> val listA = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Marry")
listA: List[String] = List(Mary, Harry, Marry, Harry, Marry)

scala> val listB = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Marry")
listB: List[String] = List(Mary, Harry, Marry, Harry, Marry)

scala> (listA zip listB).exists { case (a, b) => (a == "Harry" ^ b == "Harry") }
res5: Boolean = false
```

---

```
scala> val listA = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Marry")
listA: List[String] = List(Mary, Harry, Marry, Harry, Marry)

scala> val listB = List("Mary", "Harry", "Marry", "Harry", "Harry") // changed the last one
listB: List[String] = List(Mary, Harry, Marry, Harry, Harry)

scala> (listA zip listB).exists { case (a, b) => (a == "Harry" ^ b == "Harry") }
res6: Boolean = true
```